# Dynamic zip file checksum checking using bash

Tags: bash, sha512

I have multiple zip files that I would like to get checked if they were not compromised while getting transfered, and if the checksum values match then I need to unzip the folder.

I am able to do this for one zip file, but I want dynamic checking, so I do not have to replace the zip file name each time to run the check.

Here is what I have until now:

```
if [[ $(sha512sum file.zip | cut -d " " -f 1) -ne $(cat file.sha512) ]]; then
        log "error" "Checksum values do not match"
        exit -1;
    else
        log "info" "Checksum values match"
        unzip file.zip
```

So I have other zip files called file1, file2, and the .sha512 name also tends to be of the same name as of their corresponding zip file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using the `-c` argument of the tool?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What do you mean by `-c` argument of the tool?

Comment: What are you using to get the checksum?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams while editing the code I forgot to add `sha512sum` in the code in the question

Comment: And now go back to my first question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for for file in *.sha512
do 
    if sha512sum -c --status "$file.sha512"; then
        log "info" "Checksum values match"
        zipfile="${file/\.sha512/\.zip}"
        # zipfile="$(basename "$file" .sha512).zip"
        unzip "$zipfile"
    else
        log "error" "Checksum values do not match"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

should work. If you move the .zip and .sha512 files away after checking and unzipping, this should be sufficient. Else, you can use find to search for files from the last week:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sha512" -mtime -6 -exec ./ifscript.sh {} ";"
```

The ifscript.sh would be the if-else-fi block from above, but with a parameter instead of the filename:

```
if sha512sum -c --status "$1"; then
```

Comment: Will this work if I would like to run the script for 2 zip files at the same time?

Comment: I had mentioned in the question itself that I have multiple zip file, and for each of those zip file, I have .sha512 files which correspond to them.

Comment: I get new zip file each week which has some data in it and the zip files is sent with a .sha5112 file as well.

Comment: Well, writing a for-loop or using find to operate on certain files is agnostic to what you perform - sha512sum, unzip, wc or whatever. Have a look at [mcve] about how to condense your question and code to the essence of your question. Yes, the prosa part is about multiple files, but the code is not at all. Yes, I might have concentrated on the dissonance.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was confusing, but I had mentioned that I had mutiple zip files and corresponding to them I had .sha512 files

Comment: Is it not possible to check for the zip file and .sha512 file by the word "file" or even by .zip and .sha512, assuming I do not have other versions of the zip or .sha512 files?

Comment: I'm not John Kugelman, but I introduced $1. The `find ... -exec ` calls the  `ifscript.sh` (which is the if-block, but with $1 instead of a fixed filename). What is `{}` for find is `$1` for the ifscript.sh. In general it is the first parameter, so if you call `foobar bla 7 --nojunk`, `bla` is `$1`, the 7 is $2 and --nojunk would be $3. We only have one paramter here. But the comments can't replace a shell tutorial, a book of shell introduction and a replacement for the bash man page. `$1` is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: But then in that case `$1` would represent .sha512 file, correct?

Comment: That solution is great, but I would use bash string manipulation, rather than calling basename and forking a new process. The speed, over a larger number of files is an order of magnitude faster. The replacement that I suggest for line 5 is: `zipfile="${file/\.sha512/\.zip}"` Then `unzip "$file"` or whatever

Comment: @xizdaqrian: Well, compared with the unzipping and sha512-summing, the gains from calling the internal name changing will probably be neglectable (4ms on my system per file) but since I don't see disadvantages, I included it in my answer.